# Adjusting lstlisting frame size

Tags: latex

I was wondering how I can adjust the frame size of an `lstlisting` to my `beamer` code. This is my code:

```
\lstset{ 
backgroundcolor=\color{white},   
basicstyle=\scriptsize,        
breakatwhitespace=false,         
breaklines=true,                 
commentstyle = \textit,                        
deletekeywords={...},            
escapeinside={\%*}{*)},          
extendedchars=true,              
frame=single,                     
keepspaces=true,                  
language=R,                 
otherkeywords={*,...},           
numbers=left,                    
numbersep=5pt,                   
numberstyle=\tiny\color{mygray}, 
rulecolor=\color{black},        
showspaces=false,               
showstringspaces=false,          
showtabs=false,                 
stepnumber=2,                        
tabsize=2,  
}
\begin{lstlisting}  [title = \lstname \scriptsize bla]
library(ggplot2)
 qplot(x, y, data =, color =, shape =, fill=, alpha=, geom=, method=, formula=, facets=,    
      xlim=, ylim=, xlab=, ylab=, main=, sub=)

\end{lstlisting}
```

What I get is:

[image: Frame I get]

But what I would actually like to have is this:

[image: Frame I like]

I used to get the frame of the second picture before but I changed my settings in `\lstset` and now it doesn't work anymore and I cannot find any source that explains how to resize my frame.

I'd be really glad if anybody knew the answer!

Comment: I am unable to replicate your current behaviour with the code snippet you provided. Could you please provide the community with a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/5764) that replicates the output you show? It should start with `\documentclass{beamer}` and end with `\end{document}` and only include the necessary packages to replicate the problem. We want to copy-and-paste-and-compile and see exactly what you show in the picture.

Comment: I am curious, how did this go?  What was it in the end ....?